# Is there a way to make edges of a mesh invisible

Tags: modeling, mesh, export

In 3ds max, it's possible to make edges of a mesh invisible, so when exporting DXF into another program (e.g. Revit), The mesh surface shows up without the edges.

Note that this is different than hiding the edges using "H", since the faces in 3ds Max Still Show up. Here is how it works in 3ds Max:

[image]

Comment: You can use a **Wireframe Modifier** or *Wireframe* command from `Ctrl`+`F` menu to create a cage of edges.

Comment: Blender might have different tools and methods, what is your end-goal? Export an .dxf where some edges are visible and the rest is solid shaded?

Comment: @MrZak. I actually want the exact opposite - invisible edges, and visible faces

Comment: @Jerryno. My end goal is a mesh in Revit that does not display all the edges, just the boudnaries and the faces. In revit, there is unfortunately no way to define what's visible and what isn't. With the aformentioned workflow in 3ds Max though, it possible to export a mesh where all edges do not show up.

Comment: Hopefully the blender exporter support this, I checked and it has some features but I can't test it, don't have Revit. You can try different options in the exporter what to export: http://i.stack.imgur.com/f19mH.png there is also documentation here for the exporter: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/DXF_Exporter. If the exporter doesn't support what you want then there is no way other than scripting your own.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the settings combinations for dxf export execute edges that are rendered invisible.